# Hurdle in PLS Path Modeling

Tags: r

I am using the `plspm` package in R to model risk assessment for information security. However, when I run my analysis, I get the following error:

> Error in if (w_dif < specs$tol || iter == specs$maxiter) break : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Here is my code :

```
library(dplyr)
library(plspm)
risk <- tbl_df(read.csv("case2.csv", stringsAsFactors=F))
risk[is.na(risk)] <- 0

#Rows construction
Env <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Malc <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Phy <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Knowledge <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Hygiene <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Capacity <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
Legal <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
Malf <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Risk <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0)

#Row Binding
foot_path <- rbind(Env, Malc, Phy, Knowledge, Hygiene, Capacity, Legal, Malf, Risk)

#Column Names
colnames(foot_path) <- rownames(foot_path)

riskarranged <- select(risk, X1, X2, X3, X4, X6, X11,X12,X13,X14,X15,X20,X21,X22,X24,X25,X27,X28,X29,X31,X32,X5,X9,X10,X16,X19,X23,X26,X7,X8,X17,X30,X18,Y1,Y2)

foot_blocks <- list(1:5, 6:20, 21:24, 25:27, 28:29,30,31,32,33:34)

plspm(riskarranged, foot_path, foot_blocks)
```

`riskarranged` does not have any NAs. At a total loss here. Help would be appreciated.
Here's the link to the data file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ddhyz931c3vg0xu/case2.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

Well, I got in touch with Gaston Sanchez, the author of the `plspm` package and this is what he had to say:-

*The error has to do with the iterative part of the plspm algorithm, failing to converge. The most common reason for this error is when there is a variable with all or almost all constant values.*

Sure enough, I had three variables with the same observation values in the entire column. On deleting these, I was able to run the model. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Im seeing the same problem as you. Did you have three variables (observations) with the same values? What do you mean by this?

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, thank you for your post. Do you mind clarifying which variables you found were all constant that removing from the block helped? Did you remove these from the data set completely or did you simply exclude them in the foot_blocks?

Comment: @albeit2 quite honestly, I don't recall now as this was a long time ago. But I think I removed the three variables from the dataset completely.